# UIAppearance for multiple UILabels

Tags: ios, uilabel, uiappearance

What is considered best practice for customizing colors, fonts, etc... for a variety of different `UILabel` instances via `UIAppearance`?

As an (oversimplified) example, say I use `UILabel`'s for...

- (blue) status messages
- (red) error messages
- (gray) annotations
- (black) all others

Do I create three `UILabel` subclasses (which override nothing), make sure all my `UILabel` instances are of the appropriate class, and then set their appearances based on their specific classes as follows?

```
[[MyStatusLabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[MyErrorLabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[MyAnnotationLabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

It seems awkward to create all these subclasses -- is there a better way? Using `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` only helps when I can clearly classify labels according to their containment hierarchy.

Comment: The approach you suggest is what I ended up doing. I think it is a relatively good approach since you are creating a well defined subset of UILabels. The good thing about having subclasses is that later you can also adjust items which are not able to be handled through appearance alone: e.g. corner radius. Only issue I have found is that in IB, you do not see the final version unless you set the colors in IB as well. However it is a small price for being able to change attributes on a single line for your whole UI.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel My biggest objection to this approach is it causes a class definition explosion! It seems better if I could classify UI elements by some sort of tag and style using that -- wait -- I just reinvented CSS.

Comment: I think you either create multiple subclasses or you need a single subclass which has some form of, as you say, CSS style class identifier which looks up up a table of properties to be set. I think that is relatively simple if you do all your code by hand. However if you use IB, there is no easy way I know of to set the 'class' property. You would need to set them in `viewDidLoad` yourself. Either way you end up with a table of fake class or real class to appearance property lookup somewhere. I too had reservations, but found that I actually never needed too many subclasses.